# Wrong WordPress language?

Tags: multi-language, wp-config, language

I'm a bit confused now.

I've installed Wordpress for my Polish friend from here:

http://pl.wordpress.org/

On my local machine everything works fine and is in Polish, but installing it on the web server looks like default English Wordpress ("Recent posts", "Archives" etc.).

Why?

Every language file I found is polish (in themes/twentyten/languages AND wp-content/languages), also wp-config is set to `define('WPLANG', 'pl_PL');`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woah, default Polish WordPress package is corrupted.

Change `define('WPLANG', 'pl_PL');` to `define('WPLANG', 'pl_pl');` or download older version.

Comment: If so, please contact the [Polish translation team](http://pl.wordpress.org/) so they can fix it.